# Visual Studio Code - Removing extra information in terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am working with Python in Visual Studio and whenever I run my code it tell me all of the file information. Is there a way to just show what the code is producing and not include the file path info? It is making the terminal hard to decipher.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the output you are seeing?